# Toc vertical spacing betwen sections and getiing boldnless for leader dots

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{secdot}


\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\usepackage{secdot}

\sectiondot{section}

\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\sectiondot{section}

\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Letters}
\subsection{Aa}
\subsubsection{A}
\section{Numbers}
\section{Days}
\end{document}
```

Here's my poor WME 
[image: result]

1-) The vertical space between sections must be like subsections. (Actually, this style is better but my school don't want that)

2-) I can manage to make everything bold about sections in TOC but not the leader dots. They must be bold too.

Thanks to my future helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical space before sections same as vertical space before subsections:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\cftbeforesubsecskip}
```

Bold leader dots for section entries:

```
\newcommand*\cftsecleaderdot{\makebox[\widthof{.}]{\textbf{.}}}% needs package calc
\renewcommand*{\cftsecleader}{\def\cftdot{\cftsecleaderdot}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{calc}% <- added

\sectiondot{section}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\newcommand*\cftsecleaderdot{\makebox[\widthof{.}]{\textbf{.}}}% <- added, needs package calc
\renewcommand*{\cftsecleader}{\def\cftdot{\cftsecleaderdot}\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}% <- changed
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\cftbeforesubsecskip}% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Letters}
\subsection{Aa}
\subsubsection{A}
\section{Numbers}
\section{Days}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]